# How toMake Math.random generate number between 1 and 1000?

Tags: java, random, integer, double

So I'm trying to figure out how to print out a random number between 1 to 1000.

I tried:

```
 double a = 1+ (Math.random()*1000);
            System.out.println(a);
```

But when I try this i get numbers with a bunch of decimals. I do not want any decimals. Anyone can help? I want to get a value like 50 or 289 or 294. I do not want to get a number like 234.5670242
or 394.220345. Help if you can. will appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java) answer your question?

Comment: I figured out to use math.random Thanks for all your help

Comment: `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 0 , 1_000 )`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
     // define the range
     int max = 1000;
     int min = 1;
     int range = max - min + 1;

     // generate random numbers within 1 to 1000
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
         int rand = (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
  
         // Output
         System.out.println(rand);
     }
 }
```